# GCM registration successful on iphone but not ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-cloud-messaging

I have a weird issue where I receive the following error only on an ipad device:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 501.)
```

During the GCM registration process to request a gcm token. i.e.

```
GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
                                            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM,
                                          options: gcmRegistrationOptions,
                                          handler: gcmRegistrationHandler)
```

I'm following [the example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift) to the letter. The same process works just fine on an iphone. I'm not sure what the difference between the two devices are and why GCM refuses to register on the ipad. Both devices are currently running iOS 9.3.1.

The header file indicates that this error corresponds to:

```
// Device seems to be missing a valid deviceID. Cannot
// authenticate device requests.
kGGLInstanceIDOperationErrorCodeMissingDeviceID = 501,
```

However, I'm not sure exactly what that means. Why would the iPad be missing a deviceID, but the iphone is OK?

If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening and can share some insight, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try registering the ipad? According to (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications), You have to obtain registration tokens for each device. 501 is an Internal Server Error. You may need to refresh token or request for another one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @noogui. Where do you see that 501 is an internal server error? I believe you're mixing up HTTP status codes with the error code produced from the Google SDK. I pulled straight out of the SDK source that it is related to an invalid deviceID. Yes. The device is attempting to register at this point in time and the error is produced during the registration process. Therefore, it can not refresh or request a token because it's trying to do that already and is receiving this error.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we transitioned to Firebase as recommended by Google recently. Everything worked as expected.