# iOS - Runtime errors with GCM

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm not sure if this is an issue of the library or something wrong on our side but I already spent a lot of time searching about this and found nothing that could shed any light.

We're using GCM since a while on both iOS and Android. The application is in production and is working fine. Our iOS app collects and reports low-impact errors (basically errors we catch and handle) and analyzing these data I found those errors I'm struggling to understand.

**While registering a device on GCM with an APNS token**

*`Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=1006 "(null)"`* that according to the documentation is *`kGGLInstanceIDOperationErrorCodeInvalidKeyPair`*

**While subscribing to a topic**

*`Error Domain=com.google.gcm Code=501 "(null)"`* that according to the documentation is *`kGGLInstanceIDOperationErrorCodeMissingDeviceID`*

Both errors happens on iOS8/iOS9/iOS10.

Our app includes the GCM library via Cocoapods:

*`pod 'Google/CloudMessaging', '2.0.4'`*

Can someone help me understanding what's happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first error **`kGGLInstanceIDOperationErrorCodeInvalidKeyPair`** means that you have error in KeyPair access. While the error **`kGGLInstanceIDOperationErrorCodeMissingDeviceID`** means that your device seems to be missing a valid deviceID. It cannot authenticate device requests. From this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529728/error-domain-com-google-iid-code-501-while-registering-ios-devicetoken-in-gcm?rq=1), error code 501 was solved by resetting all data and settings on the device (factory reset) and this fixed the problem. It's also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375229/ios-gcm-error-code-501?rq=1) that the error occurred maybe because you are calling `GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler() { error in  if(error != nil) {   print(error) } }` before you had received a registration token, or had failed to refresh your token.

But I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464250/gcm-registration-successful-on-iphone-but-not-ipad) which have similar issue with you which suggests to transition to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) as recommended by Google and his issue was solved.